# jQuery: Object HTMLDivElement, get values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello there I have a [Object HTMLDivElement] in which contains data that I would like to use.

I am using *this*. For example *this.innerHTML*.

My Div structure looks as the following:

```
<div class="hour"> <!-- <-- my Object referes to this div -->
    <div class="time">2000</div>
    <img class="weather-img" src="image/rain.png">
    <div class="temp">-10</div>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the *time* and *temp* values, ergo *2000* and *-10*.

I've been reading the http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLDivElement.html documentation but cannot seem to find a sleek solution to this, my best bet so far has been *innerHTML* but feels like there should be a more simple way. Anyone?

ANSWER: var time = $(this).find('.time').text();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple enough using jQuery:

```
var time = $('.time', this).text(),
    temp = $('.temp', this).text();
```

A little longer way that was mentioned in the comments that works as well and shows a bit of chaining methods in jQuery:

```
var time = $(this).find('.time').text(),
    temp = $(this).find('.temp').text();
```

A mod edited my code which might not be right, since if there is multiple elements with the class of `time` and `temp` on the page, you could get back the wrong data. My example before edit shows how you can scope the query better:

```
var time = $('.hour .time').text(),
    temp = $('.hour .temp').text();
```

*jQuery.text:* http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Ah, I was unclear, I am using "this". Example: 
var time = $(this).$('.time').text(); However this seems to be failing !

Comment: @KarlMorrison You almost have the right syntax with your example, but it would need to be changed to: `var time = $(this).find('.time').text();`

Comment: @NeilKistner seems to return an empty String :/ I receive undefiend when using innerHTML

Comment: @KarlMorrison Please update your question with what you currently have as far as your JS code.

Comment: @NeilKistner I apologize, you were correct, post it as and answer and I'll mark it :)

Comment: @KarlMorrison No worries. I updated the answer and you now have 3 examples of how it can be done. :)

Comment: i think its not necessary use jquery only for this, vanilla is better!!

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you have the native [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

```
var time = yourDOMobject.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML;
```

*Where `yourDOMobject` references your `[Object HTMLDivElement]`.*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PhMs4/

Comment: I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getElementsByClassName'

Comment: When I alert the "this" i get: [Object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: @KarlMorrison, don't use `alert`, use `console.log` or `console.dir`. You'll get much better debugging information in the dev console.

Comment: @zzzzBov I am well aware that alert is worst case, I am however using Brackets which is a hassle to re-setup due to the fact that it is buggy(live preview that is). Hence no F12 in my case!

Comment: @KarlMorrison Added an example

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I did try "this.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML;", it did return the error I posted. Another friendly soul however answered the question via $(this).find('.time').text();. Man tackar oavsett :)

Comment: @KarlMorrison What is `this` referencing? If it is a reference to a native DOM-element, then it should work. If you have used jQuery to select the element, then `this` likely represents a jQuery wrapper around that object, so you would have to get the native element out of the jQuery wrapping object first, something like `this[0].getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML`. But if you are using jQuery, this just complicate things.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I missed out the S in elements (dammit!). Your approach worked dandy!

Comment: @KarlMorrison Great, yeah I've done that too. It's an important "S" though, as it indicates that the result might be more than one element, unlike `getElementById()` without the "S".

Answer (score 1):

This code will get you the time and temp values as strings using `yourDiv` as a context:

```
var $div,
    time,
    temp;
$div = $(yourDiv); //save the div as a jQuery collection
                   //(assuming `yourDiv` is the actual DOM node)
time = $div
    .find('.time') //from the div find the .time descendants
    .text();       //get the text from the first .time descendant
temp = $div
    .find('.temp') //from the div find the .temp descendants
    .text();       //get the text from the first .temp descendant
```

A more concise way of writing this would be:

```
var time,
    temp;
time = $('.time', yourDiv).text();
temp = $('.temp', yourDiv).text();
```

In both of these examples I've explicitly chosen [`.time()`](http://api.jquery.com/time) over [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) in case there are any HTML entities in the values, in your case it won't make a significant difference, but it seems as though you're interested in the parsed value rather than the raw HTML.

If you need the values as numbers, you'll want to cast the string value to a number:

```
time = Number(time);
```

a shortcut for this is the unary `+` operator:

```
time = +time;
```

So the final code looks like:

```
var time,
    temp;
time = +$('.time', yourDiv).text();
temp = +$('.temp', yourDiv).text();
```

Before using `time` and `temp` values, be sure to check for `NaN`.